# Does Google Adwords provide access through the service

Tags: google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

I am trying to get the reporting data from google adwords. I have gone through the adwords documentation.

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/first-api-call

It uses OAUTH 2.0 authentication. I want it to integrate at the backend. Can I access google adwords reporting api through the cloud service. I am new to the google apis. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Client Libraries: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/clientlibraries

You have a Reporting example for the programming language of your choice within the **Code Examples** section on the left hand menu.